# Changing the text color of some references in bibliography (with Bibtex)

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, color

Using BibTeX, I need to change the text color of some references. In the `.bib` file, using `{\color{} }` for the author names, title, ..., works. But I was wondering, is there a better solution?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}
\begin{filecontents}{refs.bib}
    @ARTICLE{A1, 
        author={{\color{blue} Author A1}}, 
        journal={{\color{blue}Journal A1}}, 
        title={{\color{blue}Title A1}}, 
        year={{\color{blue}2015}}, 
        volume={{\color{blue}1}}, 
        number={{\color{blue}3}}, 
        pages={{\color{blue}1-5}},} 
    @ARTICLE{A2, 
        author={{\color{blue} Author A2}}, 
        journal={{\color{blue}Journal A2}}, 
        title={{\color{blue}Title A2}}, 
        year={{\color{blue}2016}}, 
        volume={{\color{blue}1}}, 
        number={{\color{blue}3}}, 
        pages={{\color{blue}5-10}},}    
    @ARTICLE{A3, 
        author={Author A3}, 
        journal={Journal A3}, 
        title={Title A3}, 
        year={2017}, 
        volume={3}, 
        number={1}, 
        pages={11-15}, }
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
    In the bibliography, I need to highlight the references~\cite{A1} and~\cite{A2} in a different color. The reference~\cite{A3} is not required to be highlighted.
    \bibliographystyle{spphys}       
    \bibliography{refs}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following code to your MWE:

```
\makeatletter % <=======================================================
\let\myorg@bibitem\bibitem
\def\bibitem#1#2\par{%
  \@ifundefined{bibitem@#1}{%
    \myorg@bibitem{#1}#2\par
  }{%
    \begingroup
      \color{\csname bibitem@#1\endcsname}%
      \myorg@bibitem{#1}#2\par
    \endgroup
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\bibitem@test}{blue}    % <==================
\newcommand*{\bibitem@green}{green}  % <==================
%\newcommand*{\bibitem@A1}{red}      % <================== error A1
\makeatother % <========================================================
```

It defines a new command, for example  `\newcommand*{\bibitem@test}{blue}`, where `test` is the key of the bib entry and `blue` is the color to be used for the entry. I also defined `\newcommand*{\bibitem@green}{green}` to get a green reference. Please see that the key of the bibentry can not use numbers. To test this delete the leading `%` in line `%\newcommand*{\bibitem@A1}{red}`. Then you will get an error. Please see that you have to write the command between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` because the name contains an `@`!

Compile the following complete MWE

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@ARTICLE{A1, 
  author={{\color{blue} Author A1}}, 
  journal={{\color{blue}Journal A1}}, 
  title={{\color{blue}Title A1}}, 
  year={{\color{blue}2015}}, 
  volume={{\color{blue}1}}, 
  number={{\color{blue}3}}, 
  pages={{\color{blue}1-5}},
} 
@ARTICLE{green, 
  author={Author A2}, 
  journal={Journal A2}, 
  title={Title A2}, 
  year={2016}, 
  volume={1}, 
  number={3}, 
  pages={5-10},
}    
@ARTICLE{test, 
  author={Author A3}, 
  journal={Journal A3}, 
  title={Title A3}, 
  year={2017}, 
  volume={3}, 
  number={1}, 
  pages={11-15}, 
}
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{color}

\makeatletter % <=======================================================
\let\myorg@bibitem\bibitem
\def\bibitem#1#2\par{%
  \@ifundefined{bibitem@#1}{%
    \myorg@bibitem{#1}#2\par
  }{%
    \begingroup
      \color{\csname bibitem@#1\endcsname}%
      \myorg@bibitem{#1}#2\par
    \endgroup
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\bibitem@test}{blue}    % <==================
\newcommand*{\bibitem@green}{green}  % <==================
%\newcommand*{\bibitem@A1}{red}      % <================== error A1
\makeatother % <========================================================


\begin{document}
In the bibliography, I need to highlight the references~\cite{A1} 
and~\cite{green} in a different color. 
The reference~\cite{test} is not required to be highlighted.

\bibliographystyle{plain} % spphys
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

to get the result:

[image: resulting pdf]

Reference `[3]` is your colored bib entry (you see the black reference number?), references `[1]` and `[2]` are colored by the new commands ...  Because I do not have your file `spphys.bst` I used style `plain` instead ...

Comment: is there a way to change the color of those lack parentheses in reference [3]? I can change the color of the right one but not the color of the left one ...